# Calculate pearson correlation, r in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Is it possible to calculate the pearson correlation, r or r^2 value from a linear regression using pgfplots? I already have the curve and would like to display the r value in the legend. I couldn't find any information in the manual nor google search. Please advise, thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly I do not know if that is possible. You want to calculate the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient, correct? [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) is a word processor and a document markup language. Maybe it is possible, but I think it isn't meant to do that. It is easy to do it with [Python](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) (Scipy). Or you could use other programming languages like MatLab, R or C. As said before: I don't know it. But if it isn't possible, you can use Python for the calculation and LaTeX for the doc.

Comment: In package `Hmisc` in `R` one can calculate pearson correlations with `rcorr(x,type="pearson")`. An option would be to use `sweave` to access this function. Alternatively, use Lua(La)TeX to code the same function into `Lua`.